# New Line StringBuilder message Box C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stringbuilder

Gostaria de mostrar em um messagebox os registros com quebra de linha.

mas o resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria que ficasse linha por linha;

A minha implementação está assim :[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando vou debuggando, no **`builder.append`** já percebo que não é inserido a quebra de linha.

no final em return json ele volta pra chamada inicial no JavaScript e mostra a mensagem:

```
modal.window({ alert: data.Mensagem });
```

Comment: teria como postar o codigo aqui e não a imagem, aqui onde estou não consigo carregar as imagens e além disso é fica mais fácil para as pessoas te ajudarem dessa forma

Comment: Já tentou ```.AppendLine()``` em vez de ```.Append()```?

Comment: o amigo abaixo me ajudou. já havia pesquisado de montão. não tinha achado nada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto será mostrado num HTML, então, ao invés de adicionar `Environment.NewLine`, adicione `<br/>`.

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var item in tributoPagar)
{
    builder.Append("***");
    builder.Append(item.CodigoDocumentoPagar);
    builder.Append(" ");
    builder.Append("<br/>");
}

return Json(new RetornoFuncao 
            { 
                Sucesso = false, 
                Mensagem = "Os documentos abaixo já foram adicionados: " + builder 
            });
```